Do my planet's climate zones make sense?
This is just a basic version right now. The planet is like Earth in terms of axial tilt, temperature, and any other factors. I want to know whether these climate zones look right or make reasonable sense.
Climate:

Elevation:


I think you have a collection of cyan/teal colors that aren't on your color key. Could you correct that?

I fixed it now.

Assuming all white spaces are water then the large desert surrounded by narrow white space is likely not to be desert around the fringes but be rather wetter, especially on the windward side. Beyond that limited observation without topography there's not a lot to add, topographic effects like rain shadow have a huge impact on the details, especially on the biome side. As flat plain generalisations the material presented seems to work well though.
So with the addition of some topography, the central equator spanning landmass will be largely arid, if not outright desert. The mountains along the eastern margin will block Coriolis driven weather systems from bringing moisture to the western portions. This effect is flipped above 30° so the Eastern sub-polar continent is going to have a similar issue but reversed. I may have missed something, up past my bed time right now, but otherwise I don't think there are any changes I haven't noted.

I added a rough elevation map.

Not with that topology
Without a topographic map, it's impossible to check the climate map. One needs to know where mountain ranges and basins are to map climate.
Now, you have provided a topologic map, and it creates massive problems with the climate zones projected. For example, the huge desert on the western continent has no protecting mountains in its west, north, and south but a central mountain. The eastern continent's rainforest goes on both sides of the mountain range, which also is a nono. The northwestern continent ends in a southern desert, which also lacks a generating mountain range or massive land around, unless we are dealing with a planet that has eastern wind pattern - bbut even then should not reach the coast.
To fix the map, you should start with the topographic map, and go from there.
First, decide if the main wind is coming from east or west. generally, mountains create rainshadow behind them from that direction, unless it is a very thin mountain range as in the Andes. A good guide to follow is Worldbuilding Pasta or slooowy grinding through Edgar creating Cretak, piece by piece, starting after topography.
Next, you map out the ocean water circulation cells, and winds. A rough sketch of circulation cells might look like this:

Now estimate where rain falls and pressure zones happen, followed by continental zones, and from there go on to general temperature bands, refine them a tad, and only then you get to climate zones: polar, tropical, arid, temperate and continental.

Alright, I made a rough elevation map.

@J.Rubio here you go with a path to fix your climate to your topology.

The huge desert on the northwestern continent isn't formed by mountains, it exists because of its latitude and proximity to a cold current, just like the Sahara. 15-30 degrees on the west side of continents tends to be desert.
As for the eastern continent's rainforest, there are rainforests on both sides of a steep mountain range on Earth; look at Colombia, Ecuador, and to a lesser extent Indonesia. In this case, the mountains cut through an equatorial region, where both sides sit inside the ITCZ all year round.

@J.Rubio Even the Sahara has has a wetter coast in the west, but you box your sahara between two Mediterrainian seas, which massively mitigates the desert effect. You might need to add something akin to the Atlas mountains to the north and south of it, then your setup works - and pushes out the central mountain. South of the Sahara you got the Sahel to the atlantic, while in the north, the Atlas shields from rain coming in from the mediterrainian sea.

This reply overstates the importance of mountain rain shadows for large dessert formation.
